# What does next() and iter() do in PyTorch's DataLoader()

Tags: python, pytorch, iterator, dataloader

I have the following code:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

# Load dataset
df = pd.read_csv(r'../iris.csv')

# Extract features and target
data = df.drop('target',axis=1).values
labels = df['target'].values

# Create tensor dataset
iris = TensorDataset(torch.FloatTensor(data),torch.LongTensor(labels))

# Create random batches
iris_loader = DataLoader(iris, batch_size=105, shuffle=True)

next(iter(iris_loader))
```

What does `next()` and `iter()` do in the above code? I have went through [PyTorch's documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#:%7E:text=Data%20loader.,(collation)%20and%20memory%20pinning.) and still can't quite understand what is `next()` and `iter()` doing here. Can anyone help in explaining this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

These are built-in functions of python, they are used for working with iterables.

Basically `iter()` calls the `__iter__()` method on the `iris_loader` which returns an iterator. `next()` then calls the `__next__()` method on that iterator to get the first iteration. Running `next()` again will get the second item of the iterator, etc.

This logic often happens 'behind the scenes', for example when running a `for` loop. It calls the `__iter__()` method on the iterable, and then calls `__next__()` on the returned iterator until it reaches the end of the iterator. It then raises a `stopIteration` and the loop stops.

Please see the documentation for further details and some nuances: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter

Comment: Thanks @ScootCork. So in simple terms, can I say `iter()` just iterates a new random batch and `next()` displays this new random batch in the output?

Comment: Terminology is important here, `iris_loader` is a iterable, passing it to `iter()` returns an iterator which you can iterate trough.
You could separate the two functions to better understand what is happening.
`i = iter(iris_loader)` and then `next(i)`. If you're running this interactively in a notebook try running `next(i)` a few more times. Each time you run `next(i)` it will return the next batch of size 105 of the iterator until there are no batches left.

Comment: That’s great @ScootCork, this makes much more sense now. Thank you so much for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is right. I just wanted to give a complementary answer as I got confused about this topic and iterators/iterables.

I initially thought the data loader was an iterator, so thought `iter(data_loader)` seemed redundant.  But data loader is an *iterable*, not an *iterator*. Similarly, a list is not an iterator but an iterable. If you try to run `next(x)` directly on a list `x` you will get `TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator`. To iterate over a list you first have to cast it as an iterator with `iter(x)`: then you can start to iterate over it with `next()`.

The same logic holds for data loaders: they are iterables, not iterators, and you can cast them as iterators using `iter(data_loader)`.  Then to step through them you use the `next()` operation. You could just as easily break it up into multiple steps:

```
# define data loader (iterable)
iris_loader = DataLoader(iris, batch_size=105, shuffle=True)

# define iterator for use in training
iris_iterator = iter(iris_loader)

# extract batch
data_batch = next(iris_iterator)
```

Comment: thanks! this cleared up the confusion for me!